# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am working on an app with Hibernate 5.6, Spring 5.3 and we use xml-based configuration + Hibernate mapping files .hbm.xml for each entity. We did not annotate model classes.

After migrating from Hibernate 3 to 5.6, we had to use the Springs transactionManager, which workes fine so far. But since the Hibernate Criteria API is deprecated, I tried to migrate some of the Criteria API request to CriteriaBuilder and set up some boilerplate code.

```
public List<ENTITY> findByCriteria(final Map<String, Object> criteriaMap, final List<String> fields, final Class<ENTITY> entityClass) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ENTITY> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<ENTITY> root = cq.from(entityClass);
...
```

But when I execute the code, the last line throws me this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: interface com.myapp.pm.common.business.PmPropertyVO
        at deployment.myapp-clienta.war//org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:567)
        at deployment.myapp-clienta.war//org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:128)
        at deployment.myapp-clienta.war//org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:158)
        at deployment.myapp-clienta.war//com.myapp.integration.dao.impl.CommonHibernateDAOImpl.findByCriteria(CommonHibernateDAOImpl.java:554)
        ...
```

My configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath*:/com/*/*/**/integration/hbm/*.hbm.xml" />       
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">${hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer}</prop>             
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">${hibernate.connection.release_mode}</prop>                       
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

I tried to add another property, but that did not help:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="classpath*:/com/*/*/**/integration/hbm/*.hbm.xml" />
```

The mapping file for the Entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.myapp.business.impl.PmPropertyVOImpl" table="pm_t_property" proxy="com.myapp.pm.common.business.PmPropertyVO">
        <id name="rowguid" column="rowguid" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence_name">pm_t_property_rowguid_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>               
        <property name="key" type="java.lang.String" column="py_key" not-null="true" /> 
        <property name="value" type="java.lang.String" column="py_value" not-null="true" /> 
        <property name="description" type="java.lang.String" column="py_description" not-null="false" /> 
        <property name="owner" type="java.lang.String" column="py_owner" not-null="true" />
        <property name="type" type="java.lang.String" column="py_type" not-null="false" />       
        
        <property name="creationDate" type="timestamp" column="py_creation_date" /> 
        <property name="creationUser" type="java.lang.String" column="py_creation_user" />  
        <property name="modificationDate" type="timestamp" column="py_modification_date" /> 
        <property name="modificationUser" type="java.lang.String" column="py_modification_user" />                                
    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My question: is it mandatory to use the persistence.xml file when using the CriteriaBuilder? We did not use this kind of configuration before, just plain Hibernate configs.

**Edit:** After comment from Alexander Kashpirovsky I tried to change this line to get the implementation instead of interface class. But all I get is a reference to java.lang.class

```
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass.getClass());
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `entityClass` equals to `com.myapp.business.impl.PmPropertyVOImpl` or `com.myapp.pm.common.business.PmPropertyVO` ?

Must be `com.myapp.business.impl.PmPropertyVOImpl`

Comment: It equals to the interface com.myapp.pm.common.business.PmPropertyVO. Not sure how to fix this ....

Comment: Set entityClass to com.myapp.business.impl.PmPropertyVOImpl.